# record audio and system time at a time in python

Tags: python, audio

I am trying to record audio and system timestamp of the recorded time. I tried the following code, but the system time is not accurate since I am adding it manually,

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from datetime import datetime

r= sr.Recognizer()        
print("Start Time =", digit_zero_start1)
audio_data = r.record(source, duration=2)
digit_zero_end1 = current_milli_time()
print("End Time =", digit_zero_end1)
diff1 = digit_zero_end1 - digit_zero_start1
```

Please help to to do this job. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code above never initializes `digit_zero_start1`. There should be a `digit_zero_start1 = current_milli_time()` before the first `print`.

Comment: @sal I initialized it in my whole code. This is just a portion of the code. I am asking help for the method and I believe the way I am doing it is not correct since between start and end time there is some time loss. I want to tract exact system time of the spoken audio.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I don't have an answer for that.